# Children's or young adults novel about travelling in a vast flooded dungeon to reset a computer

Tags: story-identification

I read this book back in the 1980s, and it was about a space ship crew (by the set up I'm sure it was a series, but I can't remember reading any other of the series) who happened upon a world that was in the midst of some crisis.

The only way to avert this crisis is to visit some sort of mythical overlord computer - who just happens to be within a vast underground flooded series of chambers filled with dangers etc.

So our heroes set off in some self propelling pods that their ship was carrying, on an underwater journey in which they were attacked by huge hostile sea creatures etc etc.  They eventually reach the end of the tunnels and interact with the computer, averting the aforementioned crisis.

Comment: @Otis both my question and the *accepted* answer were posted before that question and answer, so whats the point in the close vote?  Theres nothing to close, the questions already been satisfactorily answered.

Comment: The point of closing duplicates is to assist future searchers, as each Q&A about a book tends to introduce different details. Linking the questions together to a common "hub" question aggregates keywords for search via the "Linked" section at right. No offense is intended in voting to close.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*[Dragonfall 5 and the Master Mind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragonfall_5)* (1975):

> Its climate system expertly managed by a Super Computer, a planet of rabbits is puzzled by the sudden flooding that has broken out. Dragonfall 5 is hired to ship grain to the rabbit clans, split into White and Black tribes, but Tim and Sanchez will be required to travel deep into the flooded tunnels to seek out the Master Mind for answers.

Comment: That will be it, thanks :)